# Menu mobile: Clicar para abrir e depois para fechar

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tenho esse código pra abrir um menu responsivo, mas não consegui fazer ele fechar.

```js
$('#menuMobile').on("click", function() {
  $('.showMenu').slideDown();
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}


/* Cabeçalho */

header .welcome .container .fa-facebook-square,
header .welcome .container .fa-instagram {
  display: none;
}

header .welcome .container a {
  float: right;
}

header .welcome .container a i,
header .welcome .container a span {
  font-size: 14px!important;
}

header .container .logo {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 15px;
}

header .container .menu {
  display: none;
}

header .container .menuMobile {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  font: 400 25px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header .container .showMenu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

header .container .showMenu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

header .container .menuMobile #menuMobile {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 36px;
  top: 30px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

header .container .showMenu {
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <div class="welcome">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="tel:5434013696"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i><span>(54) 3401-3696</span></a>
      <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
      <a href="" title=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="assets/img/logo_owlaser.png">
    </div>

    <div class="menuMobile">
      <i class="fas fa-bars" id="menuMobile"></i>
    </div>
    <nav class="showMenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#inicio">inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#empresa">empresa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#produtos">produtos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contato">contato</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `slideToggle()` em vez de `slideDown()`. Isso irá alternar entre abrir e fechar:

- [Documentação do slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

```js
$('#menuMobile').on("click", function() {
  $('.showMenu').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}


/* Cabeçalho */

header .welcome .container .fa-facebook-square,
header .welcome .container .fa-instagram {
  display: none;
}

header .welcome .container a {
  float: right;
}

header .welcome .container a i,
header .welcome .container a span {
  font-size: 14px!important;
}

header .container .logo {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 15px;
}

header .container .menu {
  display: none;
}

header .container .menuMobile {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  font: 400 25px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header .container .showMenu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

header .container .showMenu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

header .container .menuMobile #menuMobile {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 36px;
  top: 30px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

header .container .showMenu {
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <div class="welcome">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="tel:5434013696"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i><span>(54) 3401-3696</span></a>
      <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
      <a href="" title=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="assets/img/logo_owlaser.png">
    </div>

    <div class="menuMobile">
      <i class="fas fa-bars" id="menuMobile"></i>
    </div>
    <nav class="showMenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#inicio">inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#empresa">empresa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#produtos">produtos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contato">contato</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```